# Program crashes when deleting a pointer

Tags: c++

Hi guys My code is:

```
class aClass
{
public:
    int data;
    aClass* pointer=NULL;

    aClass(int x): data(x) {
        cout << "calling int constructor\n";
    }

    ~aClass() {
        delete pointer;
        cout <<"Index " <<this->data<<" calling destructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    aClass ob1(1);
    ob1.pointer=new aClass(2); // let's say the new object is called ob2
    ob1.pointer->pointer=new aClass(3);// let's say the new object is called ob3
    delete ob1.pointer; //destory ob2, which will destory ob3 in sequentially.
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the output to be like this:

```
calling int constructor
calling int constructor
calling int constructor
Index 2 calling destructor
Index 3 calling destructor //I think when ob2is destoyed ob3 will be destoyed 
                           //too, but this is not in the output even though I delete "delete pointer" in 
                           //the destructor           
Index 1 calling destructor
```

But the program crashed, I know its "delete pointer" in the destructor that  crashed the program, but I have no idea about why it crashed and why ob3 is not destoyed?

Answer (score 3):

When exiting `main`, `ob1` is destroyed automatically, so its destructor is called. There `pointer` is deleted again, which results in the crash.
Don´t delete `ob1.pointer` manually.

Here is a basic example to help you understand what is going on.

```
class C
{
public:
    C* p;

    C() : p(NULL)
    {}

    ~C()
    { delete p; }
};

int main()
{
    C a;
    // ...

    // Lets say a.p == 5 for some reason.
    delete a.p;
    // The memory at address 5 is now deleted, but a.p remains unchanged.
    // a.p is still 5, but accessing it is now illegal.

    return 0;
    // Stack cleanup -> a is destroyed.
    // a´s destructor is called, which attempts to delete its p.
    // This p is a.p which was deleted earlier.
    // Remember, a.p is still 5, and now it is deleted in ~C.
    // -> You deleted the memory at address 5 twice.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't get it., looks like I misunderstood some basic parts                                                                     int main()
{
    aClass ob1(1);
    ob1.pointer=new aClass(2); 
    ob1.pointer->pointer=new aClass(3);
    delete ob1.pointer;  // ob1 still exists in scope here
    ob1.pointer=NULL;  //  why  this point needs to be set NULL as int                                     //function still hasn't finished                                                                  return 0;
}

Comment: @whoisit If you tell me what exactly you don´t understand, I can try to help. I would recommend reading up on destructors, scopes and pointers.

Comment: int main()
{
    aClass ob1(1);    //Stage 1
    ob1.pointer=new aClass(2);  //Stage 2
    ob1.pointer->pointer=new aClass(3); // //Stage 3
    delete ob1.pointer; //Stage 4
    return 0;// stage 5
}                                                                                                                  From my understanding is that  when main begins, the execution sequence is stage 1 to stage 5, then main finishes and start to clear up memory. So ob1 exists from stage 1 to stage 5, how come its pointer was deleted twice?

Comment: Oh please don't advocate a "setting to NULL" style to hide the double delete. Yes, it works, but the code shouldn't try to do more than one delete in the first place. And what if a fellow developer recognizes this is as useless and deletes the `pointer = NULL` bit? It now all fails because a developer didn't properly think of deletion. Just. Don't. (Or rather: don't explicitely `new`/`delete` in the first place. Use `unique_ptr` and `vector` instead. It's so much nicer.

Comment: @stefan You are right, I removed the part. I wanted to let him know about the possibility, but I understand that it does not make for good code. Thanks.